# How to Prevent the non-active QMdiSubWindows from Maximize

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application with QMDIArea and i have added two sub windows(PhoneBook Window and Status Window)in to the QMDIArea.

The PhoneBook SubWindow has maximize, Minimize and Close buttons.
The Status SubWindow Has Minimize and Close Buttons and also set the width and height is as

```
lpQMdiSubWindow_Status->setMaximumWidth(493);
lpQMdiSubWindow_Status->setMaximumHeight(302);
```

So the Status SubWindow canot maximize.

The PhoneBook SubWindow has no restriction for width and height.So it can maximize and minimize easly.

These two are working fine as seperately and it is my needs.

But the problem is as below

First i opened the status subwindow and it is positioned in the center of QMDIArea .
Then i opened the PhoneBook SubWindow and maximize it,then close it.

Now the status subwindow is in maximize state.But no change in the height and width.Title bar is moved to top.

How can i prevent the status subwindow from maximizing.Is it possible?

Thanks and Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ui->mdiArea->setOption(QMdiArea::DontMaximizeSubWindowOnActivation);
```